# CakePHP ACL doesn't work

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization, acl

Hi
I'm using the ACL and Auth Component. The Auth Component works fine but if I deny some Controllers for a User it seems that it has no Effect.
The User can still visit the Page. Should CakePHP automatically hide the Page from the User?

Comment: Nothing. But I'm sure that I'm missing something. If I check the permissions with $this->Acl->check(); it shows the expected value.

Comment: It's possible that I have to manually check on every Page for the right Permissions?

Comment: I forgot the $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions'; Now the Page won't show because of a redirect loop. Wich Pages need to be allowed? And how did I enable a Controller instead of a Model?

Comment: Ok. I had to allow the display Function. But now only functions that are allowed in the code are working. It seems that I make something wrong in the Database. What's the Function of the "model" field in the acos Table?

Comment: I have my $this->Auth->authorize = 'actions'; set as $this->Auth->authorize = 'controllers'; - not sure if that will make a difference for you.

Comment: whether u given `$this->allow('*')` in AppController or PagesController ?

Answer (score 1):

you should do the tutorial http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application